# Rachmaninoff Piano Concerto 2 - technical question

Tags: piano, notation, fingering

Quick question about the following section in Rach 2 3rd movement:

[image]

Should this be played with the right hand only? I originally assumed so, but it's such a fast section I wondered if others played it using the left hand as well, just as with the following few bars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This notation suggests you use both hands. The engraver has shown this in at least two ways:

1. By alternating stems-up notation versus stems-down, the suggestion is to play the stems-up notation with the right hand and the stems-down notation with the left. (Similarly, the higher quarter-note rests apply to the right hand, the lower ones to the left. Thus while the left hand is playing the stems-down notes, the right hand is resting.)
2. This reading is confirmed by the absence of any rests in the left-hand staff; the lack of rests shows that the left hand has temporarily moved into the right-hand staff.